# How to allow users to publish data in their workspace?

Tags: geoserver

How can I set up the GeoSever security so that users associated with a given role/group can register and publish their data (e.g. PostGIS) as GeoServer layers?

I can register things as admin. I tried to allow other users to do this and set up a multi-user system following [Opengeo documentation](http://suite.opengeo.org/docs/latest/sysadmin/security/multiuser/index.html). But in the system I got, the new user, e.g. `private_editor` only has the `Layer Preview` option in the Data section, as if not logged in.

How can I grant access to the non-admin user other options in the Data, such as `Layers`, `Stores`, `Styles`, and `Layer Groups`? Which documentation should I be looking into for such settings?

[image]

Comment: please add some details of the roles and permissions you set for your user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make them workspace administrators. See the documentation:
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/layer.html#rules

The docs refers to text rules, but you can assign admin rules from the UI too.