# Allowing different users to view and edit their workspaces with GeoServer web management interface

Tags: geoserver

When different user loggeed into the GeoServer management interface, could they only view and edit different workspaces? Itried to do this by setting 'data security' and 'Users, Groups, and Roles', but it didn't work.

[image: data security setting]

[image: Roles setting]

[image: user setting]

When I logged into the manager interface with the 'test' user, I got only the Layer Preview option in the Data section.

[image]

I have tried this answer ( [How to allow users to publish data in their workspace?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225045/how-to-allow-users-to-publish-data-in-their-workspace/341355?noredirect=1#comment557447_341355) ), but still have this problem.

How should I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

In that context *write* means they can write to features in the data stores they can access in that workspace. If you want them to be able to modify GeoServer's configuration you will need to give them `ADMIN` rights to the workspace too.